# Re-enable "Update Constraint" option

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uistoryboard

I'm working on an app which having AutoLayout enabled. I'm new in it and trying to set out the views based on my experiments. Before when I have made a change in frame of any UI control, in storyboard I could see a yellow pointer (next to my view controller) -- by choosing it I'll be able to do "Update Constraint" action and will have the updated output in next run. But certainly, its stop showing that "yellow pointer" even after I change the frame of particular UI control.

Can some one please help me to reenable it? I'm simply new to this and don't know how to do it.

P.S. I don't want to do it programmatically.

[image]

Instead of that "red pointer", I would like to see "yellow pointer". I am not seeing both.

[image]

[image]

Comment: my friend...red pointer shows an error in constraints and yellow pointer shows warning ....its not shown as per your think...but shown as per your constraints

Comment: you want to show that yellow icon but it not comes because some of your constraints are unspecified or conflicting to your layout. so it shows red one...and neither of the icons are good for your layout

Comment: Ok, but when I change the frame in view, then it should show me the yellow icon, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its stop showing that "yellow pointer" even after I change the frame of particular UI control.

The red arrow simply means that [you've got conflicting or unspecified constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH17-SW1) somewhere. You need to click the red arrow to find out what the problem is and fix it.

A yellow arrow, on the other hand, just means that the constraints and your current layout don't match, so the layout at runtime will look different than it does in IB.

It's hard to see what's going on with your view because of the popup, but it looks like you have two trailing space constraints. Those might be the constraints that are conflicting. Try deleting one of them.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've added some screenshots to better understand you of my problem.